# What is significance of /,//,\,\\ while specifying name of a file using fopen() in C?

Tags: c, fopen

I am putting my program below. I am trying to print contents of a text file on screen by giving name of same file in different formats by using either of two ways –

1.using hard-coded name of a file

2.taking the name of file by user(user-input address)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()
{
 FILE *fp;
 char ch;
// char str[30] = "d:\CPRog//triAl.tXT";
// char str[30] = "d:\Cprog//triAl.txt";
// char str[30] = "d:\CPRog\\triAl.tXT";
// char str[30] = "d:/\CPROG//triAl.tXT";
// char str[30] = "d:\\CPRog\\triAl.tXT";
// char str[30] = "d:/CPRog//triAl.tXT";
// char str[30] = "d:\CPRog/triAl.tXT";
// char str[30] = "d:/CPRog/triAl.tXT";
// char str[30] = "d:\CPRog/triAl.tXT";

 char str[30] = "D:\Cprog\trial.txt";

 clrscr();

// printf("\nEnter path of file to open : ");
// gets(str);
 fp = fopen(str,"rt");
 if(fp == NULL)
 {
   printf("\nError in opening file !");
   getch();
   exit();
 }
 while(!feof(fp))
 {
  ch = fgetc(fp);
  fputc(ch,stdout); // Print the character on screen.
 }
 fclose(fp);
 getch();
}
```

In case of hard-coded address, the program is printing contents of text file for all commented formats.It is showing message

Error in opening file !

for current hard-coded address.

---

In case of user-input address,I tried for these –

1. D:\cprog\trial.txt        :  File contents are printed.
2. D:\cprog\\trial.txt      :  File contents are printed.
3. D:/cprog//trial.txt     :   File contents are printed.
4. D:/cprog/\trial.txt    :   File contents are printed.
5. D:/cprog/trial.txt      :   File contents are printed.
6. D:\\cprog\\trial.txt   :   No output
7. D://cprog//trial.txt    :  No output
8. D:\\cprog\trial.txt    :  No output
9. D://cprog/trial.txt    :  No output

Why there is difference in format of specifying address for hard-coded and user-input methods?
Also why some formats are showing output and some are not in both the methods? What is the significance of  /,\,//,\,/\ while specifying address?

Comment: Half of your examples shold not compile. Enabling warnings to see why.

Comment: 1 and 6 are the same paths with different results ... How about that?

Comment: It's `int main`, not `void main`. `while(!feof())` is as always a bug, it loops an extra iteration. Read the comp.lang.c FAQ to learn why.

Comment: @dragosht : Sorry,now I have made the changes.

Comment: @Jens : If I use `int main()`,then I should use `return 0` instead of `getch()`!Am I right?(I don't know the reason 'Why?'-Why`int main()` requires `return 0`?`main()` returns 0 to whom?)I will read the FAQ suggested by you.Thank you!

Comment: My question is - Why there is difference in specifying address in two methods?In hard-coded address,we give contents of string str[] to `fopen()` directly.Instead of that,we just take user input in another method.I think,the program should show same behaviour for any input method.I have tried by changing the file name,but there is no change in the output.

Comment: There is a difference because string literals must support escape sequences, while user input should be left mostly unmodified (completely unmodified in binary mode).

Comment: @Jens : I think I have got the answer from you.Can you suggest references for further reading on your comment on July 12 ?

Comment: Read any C book or the C Language Standard and look for "string literal" and "escape sequence".

Answer (score 0):

I think one `/` is good or `\\` is fine but `\` is a special character because it's used for escaping special characters. So, `\t` (for example) is a tab (in the source). If a user types '\t' you get the equivalent of '\' and 't'.

Comment: Why rw? That's for read/write, while rt is for reading in text mode.

Comment: @Jens I'd never seen "rt" before. Edited.